# How does dymola divide all the equations into different groups?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am learning to debug the modelica model in dymola, I could see that dymola divides all the equations into different groups. For example, in the dslog.txt file, there is information about the iteration variables used to solve 7th equation set, but where could I find the equations used in the 7th group?

[image]

Here is the setting I used currently

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the dsmodel.mof file, which Dymola creates when the corresponding translation flag is activated in the simulation setup window:

[image: screenshot of flag for dsmodel.mof]

Now you will get the file dsmodel.mof in your working directory. This file contains the horizontally and vertically sorted equations. If nonlinear systems of equations occur, you find them grouped in that file, along with a tag, which should correspond to the system of equation number.

Comment: In the same window, one can also enable "Provide variable dependencies for plotting", can also be used to explore the dependencies between variables and equations. Usually, I enable that together with the "Which states that dominate error" flag in the Debug tab.